# How to check /etc/shadow in shell script?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, cron

Linux Passwords in /etc/shadow . I want to check this file every one minute, and i want to save new changes when occurred over there.
I need this shell script and i want to use it in crontab.

thanks in advance

Comment: A little more backstory is needed.  Why on creation do you need a minute by minute check is this entreprise gear?

Comment: Is this some kind of account sync script perhaps?  You may want to consider installing and using incron, instead of using a standard crontab.  Incron uses the kernel inotify features, and you can trigger a script when ever the file is changed.

Comment: how can i use incron ? yes i need something like this even the file is changed

Comment: i am checked this script in incrontab -e but not working for me :`/etc/shadow IN_ALL_EVENTS  >> shadowlog.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Get the "time of last access, seconds since Epoch" (thanks to [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/get-file-modification-date-time-in-bash-script-163731/)):

```
stat -c %X /etc/shadow | sed 's/^\([0-9\-]*\).*/\1/'
```

of course as root, and compare it with actual seconds since epoch:

```
date +%s
```